# How to get background image of element on click event using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background-image

I try get value for style and also in side this tag values for `background-image`

**I do this little script :**

```js
function url_image(id){
  var valimg = jQuery("."+id+". cycle-slide").attr("src");
  alert('' + valimg);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="url_image('imm_1');" class="imm_1 cycle-slide" style="background-image:url('website.com/image.jpg')"></div>
```

The idea it´s that when i do click over the div, send the value of `background-image` to the script and show, but no get this because i don´t know how get the value from tag style. That´s all problem

Comment: `jQuery("."+id+".cycle-slide").css("background-image")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
var valimg = jQuery("."+id+".cycle-slide").css("background-image")
```

Like **@Musa** mentioned in comment.

Hope this helps.